# how to use gather_ in tidyr with variables

Tags: r, melt, tidyr

I'm using tidyr together with shiny and hence needs to utilize dynamic values in tidyr operations.
However I do have trouble using the gather_(), which I think was designed for such case.
Minimal example below:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(name=letters[1:5],v1=1:5,v2=10:14,v3=7:11,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#works fine
df %>% gather(Measure,Qty,v1:v3)

dyn_1 <- 'Measure'
dyn_2 <- 'Qty'
dyn_err <- 'v1:v3'
dyn_err_1 <- 'v1'
dyn_err_2 <- 'v2'
#error
df %>% gather_(dyn_1,dyn_2,dyn_err)
#error
df %>% gather_(dyn_1,dyn_2,dyn_err_1:dyn_err_2)
```

after some debug I realized the error happened at melt  measure.vars part, but I don't know how to get it work with the ':' there...
Please help with a solution and explain a little bit so I could learn more.

Comment: No any discussion on gather_() vs gather() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling `gather_` to look for the colume `'v1:v3'` not on the separate column ids.  Simply change `dyn_err <- "v1:v3"` to `dyn_err <- paste("v", seq(3), sep="")`.

If you `df` has different column names (e.g. var_a, qtr_b, stg_c), you can either extract those column names or use the `paste` function for whichever variables are of interest.

```
dyn_err <- colnames(df)[2:4]
```

or

```
dyn_err <- paste(c("var", "qtr", "stg"), letters[1:3], sep="_")
```

You need to look at what column names you want and make the corresponding vector.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help again. What if the column is not v1:v3 but some random names like 'var_a', 'qtr_b', 'length_c'? They are ordered but I want var_a through length_c

Comment: @XiushiLe, do the above edits help clarify how you can do this for just about any column names?

Comment: yes, it helps. I guess I wasn't clear about how ':' means in R. My previous interpretation is from startcol to endcol, and r will automatically fill in the rest by looking at names(df). I was trying to allow user to input a starting column and any column between starting and last column should be converted. I think dyn_err <- colnames(df)[2:4] is good enough for me.