# Pass variable to tidyr's gather to rename key/value columns?

Tags: r, tidyr

I would like to call `tidyr::gather()` inside a custom function, to which I pass a pair of character variables that will be used to rename the `key` and `value` columns. e.g.

```
myFunc <- function(mydata, key.col, val.col) {
    new.data <- tidyr::gather(data = mydata, key = key.col, value = val.col)
    return(new.data)    
}
```

However, this does not work as desired.

```
temp.data <- data.frame(day.1 = c(20, 22, 23), day.2 = c(32, 22, 45), day.3 = c(17, 9, 33))

# Call my custom function, renaming the key and value columns 
# "day" and "temp", respectively
long.data <- myFunc(mydata = temp.data, key.col = "day", val.col = "temp")

# Columns have *not* been renamed as desired
head(long.data)
  key.col val.col
1   day.1      20
2   day.1      22
3   day.1      23
4   day.2      32
5   day.2      22
6   day.2      45
```

Desired output:

```
head(long.data)
    day temp
1 day.1   20
2 day.1   22
3 day.1   23
4 day.2   32
5 day.2   22
6 day.2   45
```

My understanding is that `gather()` uses bare variable names for most arguments (as it has in this example, using `"key.col"` as the column name as opposed to the *value* stored in `key.col`).  I have attempted a number of ways of passing a value in the `gather()` call, but most return errors.  For example, these three variants of the `gather()` call within `myFunc` return `Error: Invalid column specification` (ignoring, for illustrative purposes, the `value` parameter, which has identical behavior):

```
gather(data = mydata, key = as.character(key.col) value = val.col)

gather(data = mydata, key = as.name(key.col) value = val.col)

gather(data = mydata, key = as.name(as.character(key.col)) value = val.col)
```

As a workaround, I just rename the columns following the call to `gather()`:

```
colnames(long.data)[colnames(long.data) == "key"] <- "day"
```

But given `gather()`'s purported functionality for renaming the key/value columns, how can I do this in the `gather()` call within a custom function?

Comment: Read `?gather` and pay attention to the "See Also" section. Then Googling the appropriate function name would likely lead to you [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26429582/324364).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it in a function you have to use `gather_()` like so.

```
myFunc <- function(mydata, key.col, val.col, gather.cols) {
  new.data <- gather_(data = mydata,
                      key_col = key.col,
                      value_col = val.col,
                      gather_cols = colnames(mydata)[gather.cols])
  return(new.data)    
}

temp.data <- data.frame(day.1 = c(20, 22, 23), day.2 = c(32, 22, 45),
day.3 = c(17, 9, 33))
temp.data


     day.1 day.2 day.3
1    20    32    17
2    22    22     9
3    23    45    33

# Call my custom function, renaming the key and value columns 
# "day" and "temp", respectively

long.data <- myFunc(mydata = temp.data, key.col = "day", val.col =   
"temp", gather.cols = 1:3)
# Columns *have* been renamed as desired
head(long.data)

  day temp
1 day.1   20
2 day.1   22
3 day.1   23
4 day.2   32
5 day.2   22
6 day.2   45
```

As stated, the main difference is in `gather_` you have to specify the columns you want to gather up with the `gather_cols` argument.

Comment: Great explanation.  I did not realize Wickham had imbued the humble underscore with such power.

Answer (score 2):

...and having had the same question, I now found the answer here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

You can have dplyr evaluate symbols by setting them off with exclamation marks. In your original question, the code would be:

```
gather(data = mydata, key = !!key.col value = !!val.col)
```

Comment: This depends on the version of `tidyr` involved. `gather_` is now deprecated as of version 0.8.3, at the latest. `gather_` was the right way to do it before, but in more recent versions, unquoting with `!!` seems to be the recommended way.

Answer (score 1):

Most (if not all) Haldey's functions that use bare variable names as arguments (such as `dplyr`'s functions) have a `function_` version that uses regular evaluation and are "suitable for programming with". So, what you need should just be:

```
myFunc <- function(mydata, key.col, val.col) {
  tidyr::gather_(data = mydata, key_col = key.col,
                 value_col = val.col, gather_cols = colnames(mydata))         
}
```

The only "catch" here is that it is mandatory to specify the `gather_cols`, which isn't necessary when using `gather` or can be done separately as `...`.

And then:

```
> myFunc2(mydata = temp.data, key.col = "day", val.col = "temp")
    day temp
1 day.1   20
2 day.1   22
3 day.1   23
4 day.2   32
5 day.2   22
6 day.2   45
7 day.3   17
8 day.3    9
9 day.3   33
```

Comment: Good explanation; inclusion of `gather_cols` was thoughtful.

Answer (score 0):

Note the underscore versions of functions are now deprecated (at least as of tidyr version 0.8.2).  See, e.g., `?gather_`